# Multiple Insert and Select Statements From Multiple Tables into one Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these all running as a cron job  PHP and it is working, but seems to go slow and I don't think it's very efficient. There are 5 queries and the basic idea behind it is to find new SKU's in the table and insert them into a MasterSKU table.

```
INSERT INTO MasterSKU (SKU)
SELECT DISTINCT SKU
FROM   AmazonListings
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU
                   FROM   MasterSKU
                   WHERE  AmazonListings.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU);
```

```
INSERT INTO MasterSKU (SKU)
SELECT DISTINCT SKU
FROM   ShopifyListings
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU
                   FROM   MasterSKU
                   WHERE  ShopifyListings.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU);
```

```
INSERT INTO MasterSKU (SKU)
SELECT DISTINCT SKU
FROM   eBayListings_1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU
                   FROM   MasterSKU
                   WHERE  eBayListings_1.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU);
```

```
INSERT INTO MasterSKU (SKU)
SELECT DISTINCT SKU
FROM   eBayListings_2
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU
                   FROM   MasterSKU
                   WHERE  eBayListings_2.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU);
```

```
INSERT INTO MasterSKU (SKU)
SELECT DISTINCT SKU
FROM   eBayListings_3
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU
                   FROM   MasterSKU
                   WHERE  eBayListings_3.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU);
```

I am then going in one by one in the PHP script and using `mysqli_query` to perform each individual query.

Is it possible to group all of these, even though they are all coming `FROM` different tables? Or is there a better, more optimized way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no and yes.

It is no because if you want to extract data from multiple tables that are not related to each other, you need to use separate queries.

It is yes because in sql you can use [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) to append the results of multiple queries together - provided they have the same number of fields.

```
INSERT INTO MasterSKU (SKU)
    (SELECT DISTINCT SKU
     FROM   AmazonListings
     WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU
                   FROM   MasterSKU
                   WHERE  AmazonListings.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU))
     union
     (SELECT DISTINCT SKU
     FROM   ShopifyListings
     WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT SKU
                   FROM   MasterSKU
                   WHERE  ShopifyListings.SKU = MasterSKU.SKU)
     union ...
```

Comment: Yes that worked, but the query took forever... `(Query took 34.7357 sec)`  Wondering if I can't optimize the actual Query so it doesn't take so long.. if it takes that long mine as well just do them individually... A single query takes about `(Query took 2.6736 sec)`

Comment: If there are no overlapping skus in the tables, then use `union all` instead of simple union. That will speed up the query.

Comment: Brought it down to `(Query took 29.4768 sec)`, but, anyways, there are overlapping skus in the tables.  The only one with a `unique` column is the  SKU's in the `MasterSKU` table.